# How to do elementwise multiplication between a sparse and a dense tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

Tensorflow  has  the implementation `tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul`  of sparse to dense matrix multiplication, but does it have sparse to dense elementwise multiplication (the two tensors having the same shape)? I would like to avoid converting my sparse tensor to a dense one as it wouldn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in function, but you can do this by hand relatively easily, at least if you don't intend to support broadcasting. If `x` and `y` are resp. your sparse and dense tensor,

```
res = tf.SparseTensor(x.indices, tf.gather_nd(y, x.indices) * x.values, x.dense_shape)
```

You may also want to check that the shapes of `y` and `x` are the same before multiplying them.